# How to style the FloatingActionButton from the android.support.design

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-design

I'm trying to add a focus effect more noticeable to the FloatingActionButton of the android.support.design.

So far, I've tested to add a custom background to the button:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/focus_gold"
            app:backgroundTint="#F7A200"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
```

With the drawable focus_gold being:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="#ff9800"/>
 </selector>
```

Here is the result (the red background is normal):

unfocused: [image: unfocused]

focused: [image: focused]

Does anyone have an idea to set a nice and simple focus effect on a fab button with this library?

Thanks,

Vincent

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FloatingActionButtonBasic)? check the resources in res/drawable, tell me if this doesn't help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the unofficial FloatingActionButton library! Here is the github link: https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 14):

My suggestion,

1. Get rid of the android:background attribute.
2. Move fab_gold.xml from res/drawable/ to res/color/ instead.
3. Change backgroundTint to read as `app:backgroundTint="@color/focus_gold"`

Make sure to change focus_gold.xml to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="#ff9800" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:color="#F7A200" />
</selector>
```